# How can I update php 8 on a linux server without internet access?

Tags: linux, php, redhat, kernel, version-control

Operating System: Redhat 8.4
**Internet access : no**
access to redhat server : ssl vpn
Current php version : 7.4
Purpose: Make php version 8

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Even without internet, you still need to get updates.

Mirror the software repos onto a host this server can access. Red Hat's product they want to you use for this is Satellite aka Katello, although it can be quite the complex architecture. Or you could do something else, as long as the server has access to its updates.

Right away, there are updates for you to do. RHEL 8.4 is no longer current, either update or ensure you have [extended update support](https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-eus).

PHP packaging is confusing as [EL8 introduced rpm modules](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6160902). There are multiple version "streams" to pick one, including 8. `dnf module list php`